# How can I align my angular-bootstrap div to the right and its contents to the left?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want my table entries (key and values) to be aligned properly in the right pane of the page. The keys should be left justified and the values should also be left justified:

[image]

```css
.supp-det {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d9d9d9;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 600px;
    /* padding: 20px; */
}

.text-right {
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Right pane starts here..-->

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div *ngIf="sup" class="supp-det">
            <!-- <img src="./assets/images/walmart.png"/> -->
            <!-- <div><img src= "{{sup.logo}}"></div> -->
            <div class="slp-section-right-image sup-logo text-center">
              <img src="{{sup.logo}}">
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="sup-details">
                <p class="col-md-6">Name :  <label class="col-md-6" class="text-right">{{sup.supplierName}}</label></p>
                <p class="col-md-6">Email : <label class="col-md-6" class="text-right">{{sup.emailId}}</label></p>
                <p class="col-md-6">Phone : <label class="col-md-6" class="text-right">{{sup.phoneNo}}</label></p>
                <p class="col-md-6">Fax : <label class="col-md-6" class="text-right">{{sup.fax}}</label></p>
                <hr/>
                <p>Office Address : <label class="text-right">{{sup.officeAddress}}</label></p>
                <p>Point of Contact : <label class="text-right">{{sup.pointofcontact}}</label></p>
                <p>Engagement ID : <label class="text-right">{{sup.engagementId}} </label></p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Right pane ends here..-->
```

Comment: I'd be easier to help you if we have the `css` code as well.

Comment: Thanks ZombieChowder for the instant reply, really appreciate it.
The css file code is

.supp-det {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d9d9d9;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 600px;
    /* padding: 20px; */
}

.text-right {
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
}

I am using Angular4. Also please ignore  <div class="sup-details"> in the question as I have not defined it in the CSS  file. Please have a look at the image which I have uploaded above